# Need to parse curl command as Javascript Objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

**I need to parse this curl command:**

// The user will be typing this in the textarea of react application

```js
let x = `curl 
-X POST https://google.com 
-H "Content-Type: application/json" 
-H "x-auth-token: 8d7888djmsjs55" 
-P "paramsKey: paramsValue" 
-P "paramsKey2: paramsValue2" 
-P "paramsKey3: paramsValue3" 
-D '{ documents: [{ id: "1", text: "I had breakfast"}]}`;
```

**as:**

```js
{ // headers example
  "Content-Type: application/json",
  "x-auth-token: 8d7888djmsjs55"
}
{
  // params example
  "paramsKey": "paramsKeyValue"
}
// body
body = '{ documents: [{ id: "1", text: "I had breakfast"}]}`
method = POST
```

**Here is my attempt for parsing params:**

```js
let arrForD = x.split('-P');
arrForD.map(each => {
  if (!each.includes('-X') && !each.includes('-D') && !each.includes('-H'))  {
    let _x = JSON.parse(each).split(':');
    params[_x[0]] = _x[1];
  } else if (each.includes('-D')) {
    let _x = each.split('-D');
    _x.map(each => {
      if (each.split('-H').length > 1)  {
        let final  = each.split('-H')[0] 
        let _final = JSON.parse(final).split(":")
        params[_final[0]] = _final[1]
      } 
      if (each.split('-D').length > 1) {
        let final  = each.split('-D')[0] 
        let _final = JSON.parse(final).split(":")
        params[_final[0]] = _final[1]
      }
    });
  }
});
```

This fails when I try to run with jumbled sequence of the curl command.
I am using a similar logic for headers as well, same issue with that is that it fails when I change the sequence of the curl command options

Answer (score 0):

Some arguments in your CURL command is invalid,

Use the library [`curlconverter`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/curlconverter)

```
const curlconverter = require('curlconverter');

const x = `curl 
-X POST https://google.com 
-H "Content-Type: application/json" 
-H "x-auth-token: 8d7888djmsjs55" 
-P "paramsKey: paramsValue" 
-P "paramsKey2: paramsValue2" 
-P "paramsKey3: paramsValue3" 
-D '{ documents: [{ id: "1", text: "I had breakfast"}]}`;

console.log(curlconverter.toJsonString(x));
```

Output

```
{
    "url": "https://google.com",
    "raw_url": "https://google.com",
    "method": "post",
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "x-auth-token": "8d7888djmsjs55"
    }
}
```

Comment: UNABLE to use this in react 
Error: ```You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| const REQUIRE_ERROR = 'require is not supported by ESM';```

Answer (score 0):

After working on it for 2 days, I came up with the solution, I hope it helps others:

```js
let command = `curl 
-X POST https://google.com 
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-P "paramsKey2: paramsValue2" \
-H "x-auth-token: 8d7888djmsjs55" \ 
-P "paramsKey: paramsValue" 
-P "paramsKey3: paramsValue3" 
-d '{ documents: [{ id: "1", text: "I had breakfast"}]}`;

const curlType = Object.freeze({
  PARAMS: 'params',
  HEADERS: 'headers',
  BODY: 'body',
  URL: 'url',
})

// let us parse params 
const backslashRegex = /\\/gi;
const newLineRegex = /\\n/gi;
command = command.replace(backslashRegex, '');

const parser = (parse)  => {
  let object = {};
  let _command = command;
  let rx1, rx2, rx3;
  let _splitXXX;
  switch (parse) {
    case curlType.PARAMS: 
      rx1 = /-X/gi;
      rx2 = /-d/gi;
      rx3 = /-H/gi;
      _command = _command.replace(rx1, 'XXX')
      _command = _command.replace(rx2, 'XXX')
      _command = _command.replace(rx3, 'XXX')
      // split by XXX
      _splitXXX = _command.split("XXX");
      _splitXXX.map(each => {
        _each = each.replace(newLineRegex, '');
        if (_each.includes('-P')) {
          let paramsArr = _each.split('-P').slice(1,);
          paramsArr.map(param => {
            _param = JSON.parse(param);
            _param = _param.split(":");
            object[_param[0]] = _param[1];
          })
        };
      });
      return object;
    case curlType.HEADERS:
      rx1 = /-X/gi;
      rx2 = /-d/gi;
      rx3 = /-P/gi;
      _command = _command.replace(rx1, 'XXX')
      _command = _command.replace(rx2, 'XXX')
      _command = _command.replace(rx3, 'XXX')
      // split by XXX
      _splitXXX = _command.split("XXX");
      _splitXXX.map(each => {
        _each = each.replace(newLineRegex, '');
        if (_each.includes('-H')) {
          let headersArr = _each.split('-H').slice(1,);
          headersArr.map(header => {
            _header = JSON.parse(header);
            _header = _header.split(":");
            object[_header[0]] = _header[1];
          })
        };
      });
      return object;
    case curlType.BODY:
      rx1 = /-X/gi;
      rx2 = /-H/gi;
      rx3 = /-P/gi;
      _command = _command.replace(rx1, 'XXX')
      _command = _command.replace(rx2, 'XXX')
      _command = _command.replace(rx3, 'XXX')
      // split by XXX
      _splitXXX = _command.split("XXX");
      _splitXXX.map(each => {
        _each = each.replace(newLineRegex, '');
        if (_each.includes('-d')) {
          let bodyArr = _each.split('-d').slice(1,);
          bodyArr.map(body => {
            object['body'] = body;
          })
        };
      });
      return object;
    case curlType.URL:
      rx1 = /-d/gi;
      rx2 = /-H/gi;
      rx3 = /-P/gi;
      _command = _command.replace(rx1, 'XXX')
      _command = _command.replace(rx2, 'XXX')
      _command = _command.replace(rx3, 'XXX')
      // split by XXX
      _splitXXX = _command.split("XXX");
      _splitXXX.map(each => {
        _each = each.replace(newLineRegex, '');
        if (_each.includes('-X')) {
          let urlArr = _each.split('-X').slice(1,);
          urlArr.map(url => {
            _url = url.trim().split(" ");
            object['method'] = _url[0];
            object['url'] = _url[1];
          })
        };
      });
      return object;
    default: 
      return object;
  }
}

console.log(parser(curlType.PARAMS))
console.log(parser(curlType.HEADERS))
console.log(parser(curlType.BODY))
console.log(parser(curlType.URL))
```